# Cookies or token authentication for a single user WebAPI?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, token, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new in ASP.NET Core and I am now implementing an ASP.NET Core Web API.

This API will be consumed from a desktop application in Windows Forms and what it does are calls to the database. The application will not have a log in functionality; the Web API just needs a user to be authenticated for security reasons.

What is best to use in this scenario? Cookies or token authentication and why?

Comment: You haven't clearly explained what you want. Please give more information

Comment: I want to create an ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework Core which will do mostly CRUD operations to a SQL database. This service will run in a remote server and will be consumed from a Windows Forms application. I need the Web API to be secure so I want to have only one user (whose credentials will be given from the Windows Forms application) who will be authenticated to consume this Web API. Note that there will be no log in form. So, my question is which one is better to use? Cookies or token authentication for that single user?